# how to make view which can minimize like as youtube in android

Tags: android, youtube

I need to minimize a Imageview like as youtube in right corner of screen in an application, but i do not know how to create it, use any library or not?

Comment: read this article http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/

Answer (score 8):

You can find the library here:

https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

Comment: i used  DraggablePanel   library  but my problem is  this i go  landscape mode   then video  not play in  Full screen  please help me

Comment: you can goto the link above and open an issue to the developer of the library - you should get you answer there :)

Answer (score 2):

you can so so using `ViewDragHelper`.

A nice implementation can be found at http://old.flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/,

look at "A REAL EXAMPLE, THE YOUTUBE WHILE PLAYING LAYOUT" section